# Calling an Ajax .load function from external file

Tags: jquery, ajax, partial-views

This is new to me - I may be missing a basic piece of understanding.

The following code works perfectly when inside my .cshtml file, but does not work when placed in a separate .js file:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("partialView", "controllerName")';
var parameterName = getParameter();

$("#partial_view").load(url, { parameter: parameterName },
    function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            errorCall();
        }
    });
```

Can I not load into an html document from a separate file? I know that something as simple as this *does* work from the .js file:

```
document.getElementById("pageSpot").innerHTML = "This changes.";
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you wrapping your code inside '$(document).ready()'

Comment: @dops - Well, I thought this did the trick (and didn't understand why), but it turns out it didn't. My button click event, which ideally will call my external Ajax call/javascript, *is* wrapped inside $(document).ready().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cshtml files are compiled by the ASP.NET runtime and it is their *result* which is sent as a response to the client.

js files are served statically, without any compilation, and thus the client receives exactly the content of the text file as is.

This means that you cannot use Razor within a js file, since a C# compiler is needed to compile it, and it needs to be executed within a certain context in order to have meaning.

The only part of your script which is not feasible outside of a cshtml file is this statement:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("partialView", "controllerName")';
```

You will need to either

(a) hardcode the URL value, e.g. `var url = '/controllerName/partialView';`

or (b) execute the Url.Action method within a view and store the result somewhere in your HTML, from which your JavaScript can retrieve it

Comment: this is exactly the kind of nooby mistake that I knew I must be making! the solution is perfect and your explanation is very clear. Thank you so much!